# Gitlab Runner Cache gets corrupted

Tags: maven, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a Gitlab CI/CD pipeline with multiple jobs running in parallel, each job executes `mvn test package`.
Because there's a lot of dependencies, I'm making use of Gitlabs caching feature to store the .m2 folder:

```
cache:
  key: "$CI_PROJECT_NAME"
  paths:
    - .m2/repository
```

I'm using the CI_PROJECT_NAME as I want the cache to be available to all jobs in all branches.

It mostly works, in many jobs I see the build succeed, then a message that the cache was either
created or it's already up to date:

```
Creating cache my-project-name...
.m2/repository: found 10142 matching files and directories 
Archive is up to date!                             
Created cache
```

But in some jobs, Maven suddenly fails:

```
355804 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:4.5.2:compile (default) on project spark: wrap: scala.reflect.internal.FatalError: Error accessing /builds/Kxs9HrJp/4/analytics/my-project-name/.m2/repository/org/apache/spark/spark-catalyst_2.12/3.1.1/spark-catalyst_2.12-3.1.1.jar: zip END header not found -> [Help 1]
```

It seems that the cache was somehow corrupted. If I execute the same job again, it now consistently fails. If I clear the runner cache through the UI, the same job runs successfully again until it fails for another file at some point.

I have a feeling that the concurrent runs are the problem, but I don't know why.
Each job downloads the current state of the cache at the beginning.
Even if it's not up to date, maven will simply download the missing libraries.
If two or more jobs try to update / upload the cache "at the same time", it's OK for the last one to win and overwrite the others' cache.

Any idea what's happening here?

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe it's related to concurrent workers ( Read over write at the same time maybe) if you have received the error just one time, I could suppose that it maybe error connection from the runner to the cache location, but what I'm seeing its more often, the problem is maybe concurrency.

Try to change your key to be more specific by branch/Commit hash and try again...

```
cache:
  key: $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
  paths:
    - .m2/repository
```

OR using a distributed location like S3 with versioning enabled...

Comment: Thanks. Changing the key will not work, all jobs are in the same pipeline so they share the same branch and commit. For this job, we currently use a single runner with distributed cache, but I will have to check what kind of storage is used.